# PHP Memcache Key Expire

Tags: php, memcached

I am not sure if this is possible. I was storing some information in a memcache server. The memcache entry i was storing was suppossed to have an expiry of 30 minutes. During that 30 minutes i could update the value of that memcache entry reference by the same key. But when i update the value i do not want to change the expire time. For example:

- Key is created and set to expire in 30 minutes
- 10 minutes goes by and the value of the key is requested and we change the value
- i replace the value of they key using memcache replace (i do not provide a new expire time because it is optional), i want the expire time to be 30-10 = 20 because the key was created 10 minutes ago and was set to expire in 30 minutes.
- Now since i did not set an expire time it defaults to 0 and the key will never expire.

Now, is there a way of setting items in memcache, setting an expire time, and then getting/replacing the item while keeping the expire time to x minutes after i set the item in cache?

I might possible be able to use unix timestamps instead of seconds to expire when setting into memcache, and also storing that timestamp in memcache and when i set it back into memcache i would just set it to the same timestamp stored in the value. Or is there a better way of doing this?

BTW I an using memcache and not memcached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially Memcache does exactally what you want it to.  It does its job very well, getting and setting values...  I think the answer your looking for is outside of the default functionality of memcache. I suppose you can put more control on your codebase to check a timestamp that you store with your blob and use that to set expire times for future updates?

I don't know what your using for your non-memcache consistent storage, but I would store an expiry date in that-- then use that value to update your memcache.

Comment: Yeah, i am just going to store the timestamp of the expiry in memecache so i can set the expiry back to that value when i replace the value.

I do not want to use another type of storage (like a sql db or nosql db) for just an expiry. I can do it all in memcache just by a little ugly hack.

But you are correct, memecache does what it is supposed to.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is old, but I thought I'd add a caution to gprime's solution.

It sounds like gprime's "little ugly hack" is to store the expiration as a separate value in memcache. The problem is, memcache may end up purging the expiry value while it is still needed. This can happen even when the memory allocated to memcached is not full.

(See http://sparklewise.com/?p=506 for further explanation.)

This could be a problem if your code doesn't account for the possibility that the previously-stored expiry is gone. Even if you do account for that, you could end up with values living longer than expected in the cache.

It's probably not a huge deal in 99.999% of the cases, but it's one of those gotchas that will cause massive hair-pulling and head-scratching when it does happen. Hopefully this post will help someone avoid that pain. :-)